# How to eager load sibling data using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, eager-loading

The goal is to issue the *fewest queries* to SQL Server using LINQ to SQL without using anonymous types. The return type for the method will need to be IList<Child1>. The relationships are as follows:

```
            Parent
    Child1          Child2
Grandchild1
```

**Parent > Child1** is a one-to-many relationship

**Child1 > Grandchild1** is a one-to-n relationship (where n is zero to infinity)

**Parent > Child2** is a one-to-n relationship (where n is zero to infinity)

I am able to eager load the Parent, Child1 and Grandchild1 data resulting in one query to SQL Server.

This query with load options eager loads all of the data, except the sibling data (Child2):

```
DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
loadOptions.LoadWith<Child1>(o => o.GrandChild1List);
loadOptions.LoadWith<Child1>(o => o.Parent);

dataContext.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

IQueryable<Child1> children = from child in dataContext.Child1
                                select child;
```

I need to load the sibling data as well. One approach I have tried is splitting the query into two LINQ to SQL queries and merging the result sets together (not pretty), however upon accessing the sibling data it is lazy loaded anyway.

Adding the sibling load option will issue a query to SQL Server for each Grandchild1 and Child2 record (which is exactly what I am trying to avoid):

```
DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
loadOptions.LoadWith<Child1>(o => o.GrandChild1List);
loadOptions.LoadWith<Child1>(o => o.Parent);
loadOptions.LoadWith<Parent>(o => o.Child2List);

dataContext.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

IQueryable<Child1> children = from child in dataContext.Child1
                                select child;


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Child2] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ForeignKeyToParent] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Child2] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ForeignKeyToParent] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=2

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Child2] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ForeignKeyToParent] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=3

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Child2] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ForeignKeyToParent] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=4
```

I've also written LINQ to SQL queries to join in all of the data in hopes that it would eager load the data, however when the LINQ to SQL EntitySet of Child2 or Grandchild1 are accessed it lazy loads the data.

The reason for returning the IList<Child1> is to hydrate business objects.

My thoughts are I am either:

1. Approaching this problem the wrong way.
2. Have the option of calling a stored procedure?
3. My organization should not be using LINQ to SQL as an ORM?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

-Scott

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you want to use anonymous types or some kind of container?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have should be correct, you need to add this `dataContext.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;` in addition to the LoadOptions you are already setting.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. I was able to get the Child2 sibling data in a second query using the same data context. By setting DeferredLoadingEnabled to false I was able to merge the Child2 result set in with the first query without it attempting to lazy load an entity set before I could even set the data. If anyone has other ideas for retrieval I would welcome those suggestions too. 

Thanks Nate.

Answer (score 0):

```
var children2 = from child2 in dataContext.Child2
                where children.Any(c1 => c1.Parent == child2.Parent)
                select child2;
```

Should result in a single exists query, so it will end up being two queries.