# F# SqlDataConnection Type Provider query optimization

Tags: sql-server, linq, f#, type-providers

I need some help with the optimization of a query with the F# SqlDataConnection Type Provider.

There is a table `Items` with the relations to 4 other tables:

```
Type     - n : 1
SubItem1 - m : n
SubItem2 - m : n
SubItem3 - 1 : n
```

This is the Type Provider query code:

```
query { 
  for x in db.Items do
    join t in db.ItemType on (x.Typy = t.Name)
    select (x, t, x.ItemSubItem1, x.ItemSubItem2, x.SubItem3)
}
|> Seq.map toItem
```

It produces the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0.Name], [t1].[Name], [t2].[ItemId], [t2].[SubItem1Id], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[ItemSubItem1] AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[ItemId] = [t0].[Id]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Item] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ItemType] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Typ] = [t1].[Name]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemSubItem1] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ItemId] = [t0].[Id]
ORDER BY [t0].[Id], [t1].[Name], [t2].[SubItem1Id]
```

The problem is that only the `Type` and `SubItems1` are joined. So when `toItem` is called for each entry in `Items` there will be 2 extra SQL queries generated to get `SubItem2` and `SubItem3`. This is very inefficient.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are ItemSubItem2 and SubItem3 inferred as `seq`?

Comment: They are inferred as `EntitySet<>`

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2546366/55209) is what you need. Also, `SqlDataConnection` is the wrapper over LINQ2SQL which is (somewhat) deprecated. For complex scenarios I would prefer SqlEntityProvider